# How to design class for abstract json document?

Tags: c#, .net, json

Suppose we have class `Request` which we want to serialize to json and deserialize from json.

```
class Request {
  public string SessionId { get; set; }
  ...
  public string InnerJson { get; set; }
}
```

As json it should looks like

```
{
  "SessionId": 1,
   ...
  "InnerJson": {
     "some": "json object",
     "whatever": 666
   }
}
```

`InnerJson` is some json document (arbitrary type).

Is it good to use `string` for `InnerJson` in `Request`?

Is there any good way to design `Request` class?

Comment: Yeah you can use string for `InnerJson` and use `Dynamic` to deseralize that string to an object.

Comment: What is InnerJson? Does it have same structure for your requests or it could consist of any data and changes between request?

Comment: How do you get inner json? Where you get this json and who receives this json?

Comment: @AccessDenied, suppose we receive requests from network. Request is  a Command and InnerJson is its parameters (lets name it Options). Which concrete command (and options) is incapsulated in Request we can determine by other request properties (for example, by string CommandName). So by CommandName we can parse Options in concrete Options implementation.

Comment: Does innerjson contain nested objects?

Comment: @AccessDenied, yes. It can be anything

Comment: Then I didn't quite get what the problem is. InnerJson could be a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going for a strongly typed model I'd suggest a factory. For demonstration sake:

```
public abstract class AbstractOptions { }

public class Options1 : AbstractOptions { public int Whatever { get; set; } }

public class Options2 : AbstractOptions { public string Some { get; set; } }

public class Options3 : AbstractOptions {
  [JsonProperty("when")] public DateTime When { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty("inner")] public InnerComplexObject Inner { get; set; }
}

public class Request {
  [JsonProperty("session-id")] public string SessionId { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty("options")] public AbstractOptions Options { get; set; }
}

public class InnerComplexObject { }
```

then use it like:

```
var req1 = new Request() { SessionId = "s1", Options = new Options1 { Whatever = 123 } };
var req2 = new Request() { SessionId = "s2", Options = new Options2 { Some = "some" } };
var req3 = new JToken.Request() { SessionId = "s3", Options = new Options3 { When = DateTime.UtcNow, Inner = new InnerComplexObject() } };
```

Otherwise, for flexibility, keep `InnerJson` a `string` and [use dynamic queries](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm).